# Redirect to page if form is validated

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, window.location

I am trying to use this code to redirect the user to a new page when the form is submitted and validated, but it does not seem to be working. When I submit the form, I see the console.log output test for a brief moment in the console, but the page does not redirect. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
      .forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {          
          
          if (!form.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
          } else{
            window.location = "newpage.html";
            #console.log("test")
          }
          
          form.classList.add('was-validated')
        }, false)
      })
  })()
```

Comment: If you're submitting a `form` element normally, then you need to call `preventDefault()` *in all cases* - or change the form target to be `newpage.html`. Also note that any code invoked after calling `window.location.assign()` will not be executed.

Comment: Thank you. Adding the `preventDefault()` did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `event.preventDefault()` before `window.location` does solve the problem like suggested by @RoryMcCrossan

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
      .forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {          
          
          if (!form.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
          } else{
            event.preventDefault()
            window.location = "newpage.html";
          }
          
          form.classList.add('was-validated')
        }, false)
      })
  })()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```js
(function () {
    'use strict'
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
      .forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {          
          event.preventDefault()
          if (!form.checkValidity()) {
            event.stopPropagation()
          } else{
            window.location = "newpage.html";
          }
          
          form.classList.add('was-validated')
        }, false)
      })
  })()
```